# Problems with vQMod for opencart

Tags: xml, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

In practice, I am trying to change something in some other file, but even this simple example does not work. I've been using vQmod version `2.6.1` on OpenCart `2.2.0`.

```
public static $_vqversion = '2.6.1';
```

Additional info:

1. `Linux version 3.19.0-61-generic (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) )`
2. PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17

I've already created another `xml` file that does what I want it to do (I've modified some `tpl` files, so I know stuff can be done with it).

This is my problematic example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>do something</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.3.0</vqmver>
    <author>Me (my@gmail.com)</author>
    <file name="index.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
if (is_file('config.php')) {
]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
echo "This doesn't work.";
]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

What I've already tried:

1. I've got vqmod manager installed on my OpenCart instalation my file
2. permissions are set to 777 recursively (`sudo chmod 777 -R
   foldername`)
3. Deleting vqmod cache files (there isn't vq2_index.php generated)
4. changing vqmver from 2.3.0 to 2.6.0 (or 2.6.1)
5. changing version from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
6. adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
7. "vqmod is already installed" check

Keep in mind, I've already tried to change some other php file in system/vendor/... I didn't get any error logs in vQmod manager, but it still did not work nor created cache files. vQmod manager doesn't detect any errors.

Any help would be appreciated

Installation source: https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/releases/tag/v2.6.1-opencart
I've installed it from vqmod-2.6.1-opencart.zip

Log file (I've applied error="log" to all xmls in vqmod/xml folder):

```
---------- Date: 2016-06-23 06:44:42 ~ IP : 127.0.0.1 ----------
REQUEST URI : /
MOD DETAILS:
   modFile   : /path/to/devsite/vqmod/xml/vqmod_opencart.xml
   id        : VQMOD CORE FOR OPENCART - DO NOT REMOVE
   version   : 1.4.x and above
   vqmver    : 2.6.0
   author    : vqmod.com

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/engine/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/*.php(1)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()modification\(([^)]+)~

File Name    : system/library/template/*.php(0)
VQModObject::applyMod - SEARCH NOT FOUND (SKIPPED): ~(require|include)(_once)?\((?!VQMod::modCheck\()(?!modification\()([^)]+)~

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Provide source from where you have insalled vqmod

Comment: Change `<operation error="skip">` to `<operation error="log">` and you will see the error log in `vqmod/logs` folder

Comment: @Gags I've updated my question

Comment: @tttony I've updated my question. I guess it is a bad thing if I get errors roports from a file that is mandatory & shouldn't be removed :/

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? And does index.php in your vqmod points to a right location??

Comment: @Gags I couldn't resolve it. My index.php is a bad example since it is the only file you can not change:). But I've tried to change others too without success. I don't know what is wrong. I've tried ocmod instead and everything works fine. If you got some suggestions why vqmod is causing trouble I would appreciate it.